# postgresql row level security with session variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am learning postgres row level security with session variables.

```
create table user_table (
    username text,
    idx integer
);
alter table user_table enable row level security;
create policy user_p on user_table for select
using (idx <= (current_setting('my.idx',true)::int));

insert into user_table values('1',1),('2',2),('3',3);
```

output:

```
# set my.idx = 2;
SET
# select * from user_table;
 username | idx
----------+-----
 1        |   1
 2        |   2
 3        |   3
(3 rows)
```

it should display user_table with username '1' and '2', but it shows everything. what am I missing to cause the problem?

Comment: This looks more like DB admin than programming - perhaps [dba.se] is a better fit?

Comment: You need to switch to a user who is not table owner or has superadmin privileges. Also, it's better to store values that point to db user `current_user` because you could reflect that in your policy.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html

> When row security is enabled on a table (with ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE
>   ROW LEVEL SECURITY), all normal access to the table for selecting rows
>   or modifying rows must be allowed by a row security policy. **(However,
>   the table's owner is typically not subject to row security policies.)**

(emphasis mine)

checking:

```
db=# grant select on user_table to ro;
GRANT
Time: 24.374 ms
db=# set role ro;
SET
Time: 0.305 ms
db=> select * from user_table;
 username | idx
----------+-----
 1        |   1
 2        |   2
(2 rows)

Time: 10.557 ms
db=> set my.idx = 1;
SET
Time: 8.595 ms
db=> select * from user_table;
 username | idx
----------+-----
 1        |   1
(1 row)
```

Comment: thx, it works! Also, do u know if it is possible to pass multiple session variables, e.g. set my.idx =2, my.username='2'. I try to create a policy with: create policy user_p on user_table for select using(idx <= (current_setting('my.idx',true)::int) and (username = (current_setting('my.username')). then "set my.idx = 2 , my.username='2' ", it always shows an error.

Comment: looks like different post :) ask another question - I will look meanwhile